# if statement for select option value

Tags: php, html

I have a select option for departments on a html form. After the user submits the form. It emails the respective department manager. Now I have a value called $email which I want to use with the IF statement depending on what department is chosen. Eg. IF new car sales is selected then $email=newsales@gmail.com or IF used car sales is selected then $email=oldsales@gmail.com

my code:

```
Department:<br> <select name ="department"
            <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
            <option value="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR">AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>
            <option value="ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL">ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL</option>
            <option value="AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)">AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)</option>
            <option value="BANDIT-VW">BANDIT-VW</option>
            <option value="BOOKINGS VW">BOOKINGS VW</option>
            <option value="DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS">DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS</option>
            <option value="FINANCE AND INSURANCE">FINANCE AND INSURANCE</option>
            <option value="IT DEPARTMENT">IT DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MARKETING DEPARTMENT">MARKETING DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MASTER CARS">MASTER CARS</option>
            <option value="MAYOR OF PINETOWN">MAYOR OF PINETOWN</option>
            <option value="NEW CAR PREP DEPARTMENT">NEW CAR PREP DEPARMENT</option> 
            <option value="NUMBER PLATES">NUMBER PLATES</option>
</select
```

Comment: What is the problem ??? where is php code ???

Comment: that is all my code sir the rest of my code would not be part of the question. I just need to be able to set a variable for $email depending on what department is chosen.

Comment: You can check the email values after submitting the form based on the submitted values

Comment: @VinodVT exactly how would i accomplish that sir? I have looked around for documentation but nothing really explains it to me. I have the select option working but am not sure how to set it to change $email depending on the submitted department

Comment: In option value set the emails

Comment: @J.Hof do you know how HTML `form`, `post` and `php` work?

Comment: @abhig10 I do have an understanding yes but I am still learning sir. I have updated my code with the email line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short example: I have added a submit button, when you click it the form is submitted to a Php.php page where you are going to handle if-then-else block to feed the emails.

HTML

```
<form action="Php.php">
    Department:<br>
    <select name ="department">
            <option value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
            <option value="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR">AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR</option>
            <option value="ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL">ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL</option>
            <option value="AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)">AUTO ARMOUR/AUTO ENHANCE - FITMENT CENTRE (Smash and Grab)</option>
            <option value="BANDIT-VW">BANDIT-VW</option>
            <option value="BOOKINGS VW">BOOKINGS VW</option>
            <option value="DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS">DRIVEWAY/WASHBAYS</option>
            <option value="FINANCE AND INSURANCE">FINANCE AND INSURANCE</option>
            <option value="IT DEPARTMENT">IT DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MARKETING DEPARTMENT">MARKETING DEPARTMENT</option>
            <option value="MASTER CARS">MASTER CARS</option>
            <option value="MAYOR OF PINETOWN">MAYOR OF PINETOWN</option>
            <option value="NEW CAR PREP DEPARTMENT">NEW CAR PREP DEPARMENT</option> 
            <option value="NUMBER PLATES">NUMBER PLATES</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_REQUEST['Submit']=="Submit") {
    if ($_REQUEST['department']=="ADMIN"){
        enter code here
        sendMail($email,.......);
    } else if ($_REQUEST['department']=="AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR") {
        enter code here
    }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

You can get the sendMail code from the internet. There are plenty of good examples out there.

Comment: Thank you i used if ($_POST['department']=="ADMIN"){ enter code} on my email.php file i had created and it worked perfectly. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax/jquery to submit your form then you could set an extra attribute in your 'option' tag and add hidden input to your form eg:

```
<option email="admin@gmail.com" value="ADMIN">ADMIN</option>
```

and fetch it before submitting:

```
var email = $('option:selected').attr('email');

$('#myformelement').append('<input type="hidden" name="myfieldname" value="'+email+'" />');
```

If you are not using Ajax/jquery to submit your form, you can use switch.

```
switch ($selected_option) {
  case "ADMIN":
     $email = "admin@gmail.com";
     break;
  case "used car sales":
     $email = "oldsales@gmail.com";
     break;
}
```